# Is my class safe on Android if it's not an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm still fairly new to Android, so I still have problems reconciling the Activity life cycle with what I know and am able to use as a desktop application developer.
I wrote a question here several weeks ago, about a very simple app I was trying to make. The result of my endeavor was not exactly a success. When I rotate my phone, the current activity is destroyed and restarted (as the literature I studied said it would), which causes it to reinitialize certain objects and behave incorrectly, I've been unable to terminate the app after it's done what it was supposed to.

This experiment has made it clear to me that I need to educate myself further on how to program with activities. I've spent some time searching for guidelines, techniques, best practices on how to deal with this Activity issue. To my frustration I wasn't able to find anything succinct and useful. (Believe me, I do not have the energy to read another Android book cover to cover at the moment.) The only way I can progress right now is to actually program.

So I just decided to wing it. My first thought was, if my activities are being murdered left and right regardless of the application state, I need to create something that will live on in the background. I've created a controller class, that will essentially run the show, keep the application state, run the timers and so on. The activities will get a reference in OnCreate via a static factory method, this should ensure that they always have the right one, basic singleton pattern if you will. The activities will then simply display the data from the controller and pass on any user interaction.

This should work, if my understanding of the Android's mechanisms is correct. But it got me thinking. If an Activity can be killed by the system at any point to free up resources, what about a class that is not an Activity? Can I count on it staying alive the whole time while the app is running, or can it too be killed at any point in time?

When does the termination of an app occur anyway? I've put an 'Exit' button on the final screen of my app, I've tried to tell Android that "the user has requested the app to end, so please terminate it". So far I have not been successful. I know that certain apps like Sygic do exit when you tell them to (or at least I assume this based on the app's behavior) but everything I've read so far seems to suggest I should just call the Home activity to the front (or whichever activity that is before my app's activities in the stack) and forget it.
I sometimes come back to my app after several days of not using it, and it's in the state I left it in the last time. Has it been needlessly running the whole time? How can I prevent it?

I know Android kills off activities as needed, but does it do the same with the entire app? What constitutes termination of an app, and how and when does this happen?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this excellent video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL6gSd4ugSI THis might probably help you understand application lifecycle in a much better way.

Comment: yes always, activities get killed or stopped, services run in background till specified, and a class is there as long as required by application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot here, I'll try to tackle a few of your questions but I can't write up a comprehensive response just now.

> I sometimes come back to my app after several days of not using it, and it's in the state I left it in the last time. Has it been needlessly running the whole time? How can I prevent it?

It hasn't been running per se (assuming you didn't create it in such a way that it is continually spawning threads on an ongoing basis or something) But the system is able to store a "snapshot" of your application and then when you return to it, if that snapshot is still around it'll use that to make the state of your application the same as you left it. Generally your app will not be "doing things" during the down time that you aren't using it (again assuming you aren't telling it to).

> When does the termination of an app occur anyway?

Termination is kind of a vague concept on android. The app will be in the stopped state while the user is not directly interacting with it on the screen. How long it stays "stopped" before getting "destroyed" depends on many factors. The system essentially will keep your app in this stopped state for as long as it can until it absolutely must reclaim the memory resources that are holding your "snapshot" of state. Once it must reclaim those resources it will destroy your Activity. The next time your Activity is launched after that it will be created from scratch. If however your Activity is launched before that destruction (while it is in the stopped state) then the system will use its stored "snapshot" which means it will be in the same state that the user last left it in.

> What constitutes termination of an app, and how and when does this happen?

The closest analogy to termination on an Activity is when it is destroyed. And the OS does this whenever it must reclaim the resources being consumed by your state snapshot.

Comment: that is a specific answer, as obvious you will have to explain deeply for that question :)

Answer (score 0):

I read up on Activity LifeCycle a lot too and to my understanding, the entire app, that includes the Activity and the classes etc, is killed. However, when the Android system kills an app to free up resources, it's in the most extreme circumstances. In this case, you can save your data by making use of onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() methods. Which are called in that order depending on whether an activity is being minimised, hidden or killed, etc. onPause() will Always be called (as far as I read) when the activity is being hidden, paused, stopped, killed etc etc. Save you data or the essentials in these functions and restore them in the onResume() method. Hope that helps.